# Showing full body from an RSS feed using Feeds module in Drupal 6.x

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, feed

I'm using the Feeds module to create nodes from an RSS feed. My problem is that feeds doesn't  allow you to select 'body' in 'sources' (under Create nodes -> mappings in the left-side menu).

I searched for this quite a bit but can't find any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by installing the XML Feeds parser module.